# Declare submodule typings similarly to a module

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Given there's third-party module `foo` that doesn't have typings for `foo/src`, while I need to import a submode and type it similarly to main module:

*index.ts*

```
import * as foo from "foo/src";

console.log(foo);
```

*custom_typings/foo-src.d.ts*

```
declare module "foo/src" {
  import * as foo from "foo";
  export = foo;
}
```

*tsconfig.json*

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strict": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "*" : ["custom_typings/*"]
    }
  },
  "files": [
    "index.ts"
  ]
}
```

I'm getting an error:

> Could not find a declaration file for module 'foo/src'. '.../node_modules/foo/src/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
>
> Try `npm install @types/foo` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'foo/src';`

Why is *custom_typings/foo-src.d.ts* declaration file ignored for `foo/src` import? Even if the declaration is wrong, it has to be recognized for starters.

Comment: The example is `ramda` used as module, `ramda/es` used as submodule. `ramda` has typings, while `ramda/es` doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you enable the `traceResolution` compiler option, you'll see that `custom_typings/foo-src.d.ts` is at the wrong path to be loaded by your `baseUrl` and `paths` settings: the file should be located at `custom_typings/foo/src.d.ts` or `custom_typings/foo/src/index.d.ts`.  Other possible ways of loading the file include adding it to `files`/`include` or using custom `typeRoots`; you don't have either of these set up.

Comment: Thanks, nested `paths` paths worked, makes sense since they are *paths*. I tried `typeRoots` with no success, switched to `paths` because of this recommendation, https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13581#issuecomment-273923793 .